# Correct way of changing property names on C# classes DTOs

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

I have a controller exposing an endpoint that returns a DTO. On this DTO, I am using `JsonPropertyName` for changing the property's names.
Once I run the application, `Swagger` shows up displaying the desired names, so everything is okay.
But, if I use `Postman`, the DTO's properties remain as the original ones.

Is there a way for keeping the new property names outside the REST API?

My controller

```cs
....
....

/// <summary>
/// it allows to search for a client by identification
/// </summary>
/// <param name="identification">client's identification ID</param>
/// <returns>Returns client's personal data</returns>
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ClientDTO), 200)]
public IActionResult SearchClientData([FromQuery, Required] string identification)
{
  var data = service.GetClientData(identification);
  return Ok(data);
}

...
...
```

ClientDTO

```cs
namespace venta_asistida_backend.DTO
{
   public class ClientDTO {

      [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
      public string Cli_Name { get; set; }
  
      [JsonPropertyName("Identification")]
      public string Cli_Identification { get; set; }

      [JsonPropertyName("Address")]
      public string Cli_Address { get; set; }

      ....
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `service.GetClientData()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this to make the default-json-serializer of Dotnet aware of your property names.

```
namespace venta_asistida_backend.DTO
{
  public class ClientDTO {

   [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
   [JsonProperty("Name")]
   public string Cli_Name { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("Identification")]
   [JsonProperty("Identification")]
   public string Cli_Identification { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("Address")]
   [JsonProperty("Address")]
   public string Cli_Address { get; set; }

  ....
  ....

  }
}
```